# Как передать в выражение sed переменную скрипта на bash?

Tags: bash, linux

Как передать в выражение sed переменную скрипта на bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно так.

```
#!/bin/bash

var=/path/

sed -i -e "s#/path/to/nowhere#${var}#g" filename
```